# How can I select an element which has one class and hasn't another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is an element like this in my DOM:

```
<div class="myClass1"> whatever </div>
```

And I get its text as well like this:

```
var elValue = $(".myClass1").text();
```

Now I want to avoid selecting that element when it looks like this:

```
<div class="myClass1 myClass2"> whatever </div>
```

So, the scenario is: get the value of `div.myClass1` when that element doesn't have `myClass2` class name. How can I do that?

Comment: `jQuery('.myClass1:not(.myClass2)')`? Or give `myClass1` something unique

Answer (score 0):

Try `:not()` selector:

`var elValue = $(".myClass1:not(.myClass2)").text();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var elValue = $(".myClass1").not(".myClass2").text();
```

http://api.jquery.com/not/